# How to change the value of the string

Tags: python

I am developing a program that generates IDs of 25 digits formed by different data parts.

In this ID I have one part that is a counter. My counter begins at "A000" and each iteration changes like the following:

A000, A001,A002... A999,B000,B001...Z999...A000

First of all we iterate the numbers and then, the letter.

My program works and it generates the IDs, but when we have to change the letter (for example when we have to change from A999 to B000) I cannot change the letter.

```
if (numCounterInt == 999):
    print("HE ENTRADO")
    numCounterInt = 0
    numCounter = "000"
    if (letraCounter == "A"):
        print("CAMBIAMOS A B")
        letraCounter = "B"
```

print messages work including

Comment: What does "cannot change the letter" mean exactly? The code you posted is too incomplete to tell. Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve].

Comment: I think it is clear enough but I will clarify if it is needed. I have an alphanumeric counter. In my code I separate this counter in letters and numbers. I iterate the numbers to 999 and the next iteration will be 000 again. The changement on this iteration is the letter, if it was "A" next letter will be "B". Then, if we had the iteration before "A999" next will be "B000". As you edited, print messages work but my letter do not changes in "A999" and it generates "A000" again

Comment: Note that you might be better off just counting with an integer, and *formatting* it as you ID. ``lambda num: chr(num // 1000 + 65) + str(num % 1000)`` transform any number between 0 and 25999 to your desired format.

Comment: How do you generate the actual IDs? You only show how you set the individual parts, yet your problem is that your ouput of the whole is not working.

Comment: I get the counter from a txt. My counter is formed by AXXX where X are numbers. I separe it and I parse "XXX" to number. After that when XXX =999 I change my letter I got before

Comment: Please show the relevant *code* for us to reproduce your problem. There is obviously a problem and we cannot guess what is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Finally I solved it. It was not in the code I put you. Sorry for that and thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create lists that contain alphas and nums, then combine them and keep them in a list

```
import string
from itertools import product

alphas = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
nums = ['{:03}'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
user_name = [''.join(i) for i in product(alphas, nums)]
```

Results:

```
['A000', 'A001', 'A002', 'A003'..... 'Z999']
```

After that, you can assign user_name based on its index.